# "requests-html" proxy setting not working

Tags: python-requests-html

I'm using the following code to set the proxy for the `HTMLSession`, `get()` method. Still, it uses my IP instead of the proxy IP.

proxy string format:

```py
http://username:password@ip:port

r = session.get('https://whatismyipaddress.com/', proxies={'http': proxy})
r.html.find('p.ip-address')[0].text
```

above print the following which is my current IP address.

```
'IPv4:? The most common IP version is assigned by ISPs. 175.157.?.?'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 'https' in proxies:

```py
proxy = 'http://username:password@ip:port'
r = session.get('https://whatismyipaddress.com/', proxies={'http': proxy, 'https': proxy})
```